# Upserting multiple vertices in Gremlin from Go

Tags: go, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I've written the following Go code to upsert and array of vertices in Go. First off, the code has not effect. It doesn't error out, it just doesn't do the upserts.

Second, is this the most efficient way to upsert a batch of vertices using Gremlin?

```
func (n NeptuneGremlinGraph) Put(assetID string, version string, records []les.DeltaEditRecord) error {
    g := gremlin.Traversal_().WithRemote(n.connection)
    for _, r := range records {
        promise := g.V().HasLabel("Entity").Property("asset_id", assetID).Property("version", version).Property("entity_id", r.EntityID).Fold().
            Coalesce(g.V().Unfold(),
                g.AddV("Entity").Property("asset_id", assetID).Property("version", version).Property("entity_id", r.EntityID)).Iterate()
        err := <-promise
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

This is using the tinkerpop Go driver gremlingo.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Coalesce` looks wrong. Can you please try

```
Coalesce(AnonT.Unfold(),
         AnonT.AddV("Entity").Property("asset_id", assetID).Property("version", version).Property("entity_id", r.EntityID)).Iterate()
```

This assumes `AnonT` was defined as

```
var AnonT = gremlingo.T__
```

In your original query, the `Coalesce` started with `g.V().Unfold()` which is going to always yield results (unless the graph is empty) so the alternate part of the `Coalesce` will never get executed.

Using the `Fold` ... `Coalesce` pattern is a perfectly reasonable way to do a "create if not exist" type of operation. Note that in Apache TinkerPop 3.6.x a new step called `MergeV` (along with a corresponding `MergeE`) was added. This will help simplify these types of tasks.

It looks from your code sample that you may be using Amazon Neptune. If so, support for `MergeV` is not quite there yet in Neptune, so keep using the `Coalesce` idiom until Neptune adds that support.

**UPDATED based on comment discussion**

Also, as discussed in the comments, this line

```
g.V().HasLabel("Entity").Property("asset_id", assetID).Property("version", version).Property("entity_id", r.EntityID).Fold().
```

should use `Has` instead of `Property`

**UPDATED 2023-03-17**

In TinkerPop release 3.6.0 two new steps `mergeV` and `mergeE` were added to Gremlin. These are designed to make the "create if not exist" or "upsert" type queries much easier to write. In most cases these new steps will replace the former `fold...coalesce` pattern. As of version 1.2.1.0 Amazon Neptune now supports the required TinkerPop version. For further reading please checkout the [TinkerPop documentation](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#mergevertex-step)

Comment: Thank you. That worked, though the outcome was not what I wanted. My test case has 10 delta edit records. All 10 records have the same asset_id and version, and an entity_id that is one of 3 unique values amongst the 10. I expected that three new vertices would be created, one for each unique value of entity_id,  but a single vertex was created with an entity_id property that has three values. i.e. entity_id: #root,#resources,#artwork.

How can I modify this query to instead result in 3 entities, one for each unique value of entity_id?

Comment: Duh. Property should be Has, in the query part. Now I get what I expected.

Comment: I was just about to update my answer. Glad you already spotted that. Nice to see people using the Go driver, that's the most recent one added to the TinkerPop supported client family. I'll update the answer anyway in case others find the question.