# Error creating graph in Neptune using Gremlin from Go

Tags: go, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm creating/updating (upsert) a graph using Gremlin. I'm using Go, the Gremlin go driver Gremlingo, and the graph database AWS Neptune.

I'm getting the following error back from Neptune:

```
2023/01/27 12:44:59 Error occurred during operation gremlinServerWSProtocol.responseHandler(): 'E0502: error in read loop, error message '{code:243 message:{"code":"InvalidParameterException","requestId":"12de5fcc-16f0-4ac3-a64a-7f0c0068eff6","detailedMessage":"The provided traverser does not map to a value: v[0ac2fa61-8182-ec95-3fb2-8946dae540de][NeptuneVertex]->[SelectOneStep(last,e,null)][DefaultGraphTraversal] parent[[NeptuneGraphQueryStep(Vertex), NeptuneTraverserConverterStep, NeptuneMemoryTrackerStep, FoldStep, CoalesceStep([[UnfoldStep, AddPropertyStep({value=[{\"mimeType\":\"application/vnd.adobe.hz.express+dcx\",\"docModelVersion\":95,\"draftDocumentModels\":\"\"}], key=[value]})], [AddVertexStep({component_id=[DocumentProperties], label=[Component], asset_id=[urn:aaid:sc:VA6C2:004ba5d7-5e1c-47a6-824a-0d0822e6415b], entity_id=[#root], version=[#head], value=[{\"mimeType\":\"application/vnd.adobe.hz.express+dcx\",\"docModelVersion\":95,\"draftDocumentModels\":\"\"}]})]]), NoOpBarrierStep(null), AddEdgeStep({~to=[[SelectOneStep(last,e,null)]], label=[ATTACHED_TO]}), NoneStep]]"} attributes:map[]}'. statusCode: 243'
```

while executing the following query.

```
func (n NeptuneGremlinGraph) Put(assetID string, version string, records []les.DeltaEditRecord) error {
    g := gremlin.Traversal_().WithRemote(n.connection)
    anonT := gremlin.T__
    for _, r := range records {
        promise := g.V().HasLabel("Entity").
            Has("asset_id", assetID).
            Has("version", version).
            Has("entity_id", r.EntityID).
            Fold().
            Coalesce(anonT.Unfold(),
                anonT.AddV("Entity").
                    Property("asset_id", assetID).
                    Property("version", version).
                    Property("entity_id", r.EntityID)).
            As("e").
            V().HasLabel("Component").
            Has("asset_id", assetID).
            Has("version", version).
            Has("entity_id", r.EntityID).
            Has("component_id", r.ComponentID).
            Fold().
            Coalesce(anonT.Unfold().
                Property("value", r.Value),
                anonT.AddV("Component").
                    Property("asset_id", assetID).
                    Property("version", version).
                    Property("entity_id", r.EntityID).
                    Property("component_id", r.ComponentID).
                    Property("value", r.Value)).
            AddE("ATTACHED_TO").To("e").Iterate()
        err := <-promise
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

I am not sure what is wrong, and cannot completely interpret the error message. Can anyone see what is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0):

After a `Fold` any prior labels from `As` steps are lost. I suspect what is happening here is that the `AddE` step is failing because the `To('e')` is not resolving. Try changing `As('e')` to `Store('e')` and see if that helps. Also you will need to change the `To` to `To(Cap('e').Unfold())`

Here is a simple example using the Gremlin Console

```java
gremlin> g.V(1).store('e').V(2).addE('test').to(cap('e').unfold())

==>e[61286][2-test->1]
```

As we discussed a little in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75261601/upserting-multiple-vertices-in-gremlin-from-go) , the new `MergeV` and `MergeE` steps will help a lot in such cases. You will only run into the issue you just encountered when you have multiple `Fold`...`Coalesce` patterns chained together.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed my problem. I will look forward to the MergeV and MergeE steps!